# Simulate BPMN diagrams

Tags: simulation, visio, bpmn

I want to create a a main process in BPMN(High level BPMN) that has several sub process and I want to hide them from the modeler,that is I will provide only the main process for the modeler.
For ex.In a customer registration process I will provide the him only to see an icon called "Customer Registration". Underlying processes will not be visible to him. I'm going to use existing BPMN for this process and will develop an addin for visio.Will that be possible?How can I do this?
Is there any way to simulate a BPMN digram that is drawn in visio other that Rockwell Arena?

Thank you.
Regards,
Nilani.

Answer (score 0):

All this has been taken care by [Oryx](http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/). You no need to reinvent.

http://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/Oryx/BPMN

Comment: Yes,but I want to make it domain specific,then any person in that domain will be able to model without the understanding of BPMN notations?I'm developing for health care.What my ultimate objective is doctors or nurses will be able to model there hospital process without the knowledge or with very little knowledge of BPMN?

Comment: I am in the same boat as you. I believe you can do this with the Oryx plugins. If you are going to research on this then please share what you find.

Comment: Is there anyway that I could see BPEL/XML code that have generated for my BPMN diagram?I mean a software tool or any?